# Why does cv2.imread output a matrix of zeros for a 32-bit image even when using cv.IMREAD_ANYDEPTH?

Tags: python, image, opencv

I'm using OpenCV version 4.1.1 in Python and cannot get a legitimate reading for a 32-bit image, even when I use cv.IMREAD_ANYDEPTH. Without cv.IMREAD_ANYDEPTH, it returns as None type; with it, I get a matrix of zeros. The issue persists after reinstalling OpenCV. os.path.isfile returns True. The error was replicated on another computer. The images open in ImageJ, so I wouldn't think they're corrupted. I would rather use Skimage since it reads the images just fine, but I have to use OpenCV for what I'm working on. Any advice is appreciated.

```
img = cv2.imread(file,cv2.IMREAD_ANYDEPTH)
```

Link for the image: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1IiHbemsmn2gLW12RG3i9fLYZQW2u8sQw/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Please post your code and a link to your input image. By 32-bit image, do you mean 4 channels of 8-bits or one channel of 32-bits?

Comment: how did you see that they are all zeros?

Comment: @fmw42 I added a link and the code to the question. It is one channel of 32-bits.

Comment: @Micka I'm using Spyder and opened it from variable explorer.

Comment: Your image is all zeros.  I downloaded it and ImageMagick tells me that it has all zeros. I also loaded it into Photoshop and it is totally black. So again all zeros.

Comment: @fmw42 The image does have some signal, albeit quite dim. Here's a link with a brightness and contrast enhanced version: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1w5BrCzCHweWYr8gI9bAF_kryL5TPf-OU/view?usp=sharing. What confuses me is that Skimage will read it just fine, but OpenCV is having issues.

Comment: Is it 32-bit integer or float?

Comment: It is 32-bit float.  So when you read the image, is there a way to tell cv2.imread, that it is float?

Comment: Perhaps it is read OK and it is the view that is the issue. Perhaps print parts of the image in Python/Numpy to see what values you have.

Comment: @fmw42 CV_32F should make it read it as a float, but it isn't fixing it. I used cv2.imread(file, cv2.IMREAD_ANYDEPTH | cv2.CV_32F). I tried it with and without IMREAD_ANYDEPTH with the same results. I also tried CV_32FC1 and tried C2, C3, C4 just to see what'd happen. I printed parts of the image in Python and it looks the same as in variable explorer.

Comment: "I used `cv2.imread(file, cv2.IMREAD_ANYDEPTH | cv2.CV_32F)`" -- that's a nonsense combination of flags. The only named constants to use with `imread` are [part of enum cv::ImreadModes](https://docs.opencv.org/4.5.2/d8/d6a/group__imgcodecs__flags.html#ga61d9b0126a3e57d9277ac48327799c80). Sinze the value of `cv2.CV_32F` is `5`, what you're effectivelly calling `imread` with is `cv2.IMREAD_ANYDEPTH | cv2.IMREAD_COLOR` which contradicts itself.

Comment: Anyway, the underlying array of bytes loaded from the image using `cv2.IMREAD_ANYDEPTH` is correct, it's just not being interpreted right. You can use `img.view(np.uint32)` to have numpy treat it as an array of unsigned ints, and it suddenly seems to make much more sense (max value 40950, instead of 5.7383172e-41). I also get the same thing if I load the image using Pillow.

Comment: @DanMašek `img.view(np.uint32)` was exactly what I needed. Thank you!

Comment: Just an example https://pastebin.com/0L6vkLiN that gives me as the scaled-to-8bit image this thing: https://i.imgur.com/OYYsFHB.png

Comment: @fmw42 Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears to be some bug in how OpenCV loads such TIFF images. Pillow seems to load the image in a sensible way. Running

```
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np

img_pil = Image.open('example_image.tiff')
img_pil_cv = np.array(img_pil)
print(img_pil_cv.dtype)
print(img_pil_cv.max())
```

I get

```
int32
40950
```

as an output, which looks reasonable enough.

When I do

```
import cv2
img_cv = cv2.imread('example_image.tiff', cv2.IMREAD_ANYDEPTH)
print(img_cv.dtype)
print(img_cv.max())
```

I get

```
float32
5.73832e-41
```

which is obviously wrong.

Nevertheless, the byte array holding the pixel data is correct, it's just not being interpreted correctly. You can use [`numpy.ndarray.view`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.view.html) to reinterpret the datatype of a numpy array, so that it's treated as an array if 32bit integers instead.

```
img_cv = cv2.imread('example_image.tiff', cv2.IMREAD_ANYDEPTH)
img_cv = img_cv.view(np.int32)
print(img_cv.dtype)
print(img_cv.max())
```

Which prints out

```
int32
40950
```

Since the maximum value is small enough for 16bit integer, let's convert the array and see what it looks like

```
img_cv_16bit = img_cv.astype(np.uint16)
cv2.imwrite('output_cv_16bit.png', img_cv_16bit)
```

[image: 16 bit unscaled]

OK, there are some bright spots, and a barely visible pattern. With a little adjustment, we can get something visible:

```
img_cv_8bit = np.clip(img_cv_16bit // 16, 0, 255).astype(np.uint8)
cv2.imwrite('output_cv_8bit.png', img_cv_8bit)
```

[image: scaled down by 16 and cast to 8bit]

That looks quite reasonable now.